# Create a hive table by processing TextOutputFormat

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, hive, mapreduce, hdfs

I am using Hadoop Mapreduce to pass data from MongoDB to HDFS in TextOutputFormat format.
I want to process data received in TextOutputFormat format and create it in hive table format, but it doesn't work well so I need help.

The data format within TextOutputFormat is as below.

```
12a34b567cd8e91f234g56h7     {"_id": {"$oid": "12a34b567cd8e91f234g56h7"}, "dateTime": {"$date": 1690377256491}, "agree": "Y", "connIp": "10.10.10.10", "userId ": "12345678"}
12a34b567cd8e91f234g56h7     {"_id": {"$oid": "12a34b567cd8e91f234g56h7"}, "dateTime": {"$date": 1690377256491}, "agree": "Y", "connIp": "10.10.10.10", "userId ": "12345678"}
```

Rows are separated by newlines and columns are separated by tabs.
I want to make this a hive table consisting of columns id, dateTime, agree, connIp, userId (it doesn't matter if the column names are oid and date)
I tried using serde, lateral view explode, etc. for this, but couldn't get the desired result.

Can I get some advice on how to create the table?
It doesn't matter if you use something like lateral view explode.

When creating a table, apply **ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'** and view the view with lateral view explode.
--> You can obtain a table consisting of id and value, but the view search where the elements in value are columns fails.

Use jsonSerde when creating tables
--> An error occurs because the TextOutputFormat file is not in json format.